# Power Query List.Generate performance

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have a list of items (project keys) over which I need to iterate and call an API to return JSON payload (squad names). These responses need to be stored in a table that also has the item from the list which generated it like this:

| Project Key | Squad |
| --- | --- |
| ProjectA | Squad1 |
| ProjectA | Squad2 |
| ProjectB | Squad2 |

My current query runs DOG slow and looks like this:

```fs
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="projectList"]}[Content],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Project Key", type text}, {"Found in Jira", type logical}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Found in Jira] = true)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Found in Jira"}),
    tableOfProjects = #"Removed Columns",
    listOfProjects = Table.ToList(tableOfProjects),

    GetSquadValues = (ProjectKey) =>
        let
            SquadSource = Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://localhost:3000/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta?projectKeys=" & ProjectKey & "&issuetypeNames=Epic&expand=projects.issuetypes.fields")),
            projects = SquadSource[projects],
            projects1 = projects{0},
            issuetypes = projects1[issuetypes],
            issuetypes1 = issuetypes{0},
            fields = issuetypes1[fields],
            #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(fields),
            #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Converted to Table", each ([Name] = "customfield_10293")),
            #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Name"}),
            #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Value", {"allowedValues"}, {"allowedValues"}),
            #"Expanded allowedValues" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Value", "allowedValues"),
            #"Expanded allowedValues1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded allowedValues", "allowedValues", {"value"}, {"allowedValues.value"}),
            #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded allowedValues1",{{"allowedValues.value", "allowedValues"}}),
            tableOfProjectSquads = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Project Key", (row) => ProjectKey)
        in
            tableOfProjectSquads,

    listOfSquads = List.Generate(
        () => [i=-1, table=#table({},{})],  // initialize loop variables
        each [i] < List.Count(listOfProjects),
        each [
            i=[i]+1,
            table=GetSquadValues(listOfProjects{i}) 
        ],
        each [table]
    ),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(listOfSquads, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"allowedValues", "Project Key"}, {"allowedValues", "Project Key"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded Column1",{"Project Key", "allowedValues"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

How can I improve the performance?

Comment: Did you try evaluating the performance by running this through [Vertipaq Analyzer](https://www.sqlbi.com/tools/vertipaq-analyzer/) ?

Comment: #1 This doesn't answer your question, but if I'm reading correctly, your code can be simplified by using `Table.AddColumn(tableOfProjects, "expandMe", GetSquadValues, type table)` (or maybe `Table.TransformColumns` too). I think it doesn't make sense to use `List.Generate` here since you basically just want to invoke `GetSquadValues` for every project key. #2 My limited understanding of optimising code is to profile which part takes the longest to run and then proceed to

Comment: optimise that part. Optimising without profiling is basically just guessing. For example, is your code slow because it can be written more efficiently or because a lot of time is spent waiting to receive the JSON? #3 In the `GetSquadValues` function, why is there a `#"Renamed Columns"` step when you could have specified the new name in the `#"Expanded allowedValues1"` step? Maybe your code can be re-written without redundant steps, but this may not really help with improving code's performance.